# TextView Filling entire row programmatically

Tags: android, textview, tablerow

In my code I create rows dynamically, for some rows I need `TextView` to fill the entire row instead of the first cell, i.e.:

```
--------------------
|    Welcome       |
|------------------|
|cell1|cell2|cell3 |
|------------------|
|cell1|cell2|cell3 |
--------------------
```

my code:

```
TableRow welcome_row= new TableRow(getBaseContext());
TextView welcome= new TextView(getBaseContext());
welcome.setText("Welcome");
table.addView(welcome_row,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

How can I make *welcome* `Textview` fill entire row?

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15590473/programmatically-adding-rows-to-tablelayout-leads-to-incorrect-view-hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(this);
        tableLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        TableRow welcome_row = new TableRow(this);
        welcome_row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        welcome_row.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        welcome_row.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);

        TextView welcome = new TextView(this);
        welcome.setText("Welcome!");
        welcome.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

        // add textview to table row
        welcome_row.addView(welcome);

        // add table row to table
        tableLayout.addView(welcome_row);

        setContentView(tableLayout);
    }
}
```